# Android receive data from two bluetooth device Simultaneously

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I am developing an app which can receive data from **two non-android bluetooth devices simultaneously**. I can connect and receive data from single device, but how can I receive data from more than **one devices simultaneously**?

Can anyone help me or provide me some example code?

Thank you

Comment: Take a look at this https://tsicilian.wordpress.com/2012/11/06/bluetooth-data-transfer-with-android/